# jquery close datepicker when input lose focus

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'm using datepicker inside my input , my last field is the datepicker input , after validating it i want to set focus on another input inside my form , but the problem is the datepicker is not closed even taht it does not have the focus..

how can I close the datepicker when i set the focus on another input field?
(I tried .datepicker("hide"); but it did not worked for me).

**UPDATE:**
this is my code:

```
$(function()
    {    $( "#test_date" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
        });
        });
 //when i call my function:
 $( "#test_date" ).datepicker("hide"); //---> this does not work!
```

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: .datepicker("hide"); should work, please show some code.

Comment: How did you use `.datepicker('hide')`? Some code to look at would help.

Comment: I've updated my question with my code..

Comment: see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333571/jquery-ui-datepicker-doesnt-hide-when-click-outside/20606429#20606429

hope it will help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Question Edited** to work with the latest version of jqueryUI

JqueryUi auto-closes the datepicker when an element loses focus by user interaction, but not when changing focus with JS.

Where you are calling your function which removes focus from the input assigned a datepicker you also need to call:

```
 $("#test_date ~ .ui-datepicker").hide();
```

This code is hiding the datepicker which is a sibling (~) of #test_date.

Comment: This causes the datepicker to hide if you click the next or previous month buttons.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan You have added the selector of the jquery datepicker to the value "dateInputElementIdGoesHere" above. This is not my intention. It should be the selector of an input

Comment: @MarkW No, I'm using the selector of the input.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan Does the selector also match the datepicker's previous/next month buttons?

Comment: @MarkW No, it matches only the input.

Comment: @EdwardOlamisan would you post your code? (either question or via jsfiddle) I'm interested in solving the problem

Comment: @MarkW, this solution will close the calendar if the user tries to use the calender( ie if they try to use the calendar blur of the input will trigger).

Comment: @RayLoveless Not quite sure what you mean. This solution is intended to close the datepicker/calendar when the input loses focus

Comment: @MarkW, see Edwards comments. he's having the same issue. If you try the code you'll see exactly what we mean.

Comment: @RayLoveless I have edited my code as I mistakenly had 2 different IDs which were meant to refer to the same element. Perhaps this is the problem you were having

Comment: @MarkW, Still haveing the same issue as Edward initially mentioned at the top with clicking on the next month.  Do you have a working online example?

Comment: @RayLoveless Thanks. I understand what is meant now. I think my original answer worked with an older version of JQueryUI. (Note Edward's comment being 3 years after my answer) I have now updated to work with the latest jqueryUI.

Comment: jquery v1.11.2, jqueryUI v1.12.1, the above doesn't work at all. `.ui-datepicker` is not a sibling anymore, it's declared as the last element in body.

Answer (score 8):

To be dynamic, and using the class assigned by jQueryui you can do:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").on("blur", function(e) { $(this).off("focus").datepicker("hide"); });
```

```js
;(function() {
 function eventOnFocusDP(e, par) {
  if (par.ver == $.fn.jquery) {
   if (this.tmr) clearTimeout(this.tmr);
   par.lbl1.text(par.msgs[1]);
   this.tmr = setTimeout(function() { par.inpNP.focus(); }, par.secs*1e3);
  }
 }
 
 function eventOnFocusNP(e, par) {
  if (par.ver == $.fn.jquery) {
   par.lbl1.text(par.msgs[0]);
   par.lbl2.text(par.msgs[2]);
  }
 }
 
 function eventOnBlurNP(e, par) {
  if (par.ver == $.fn.jquery) par.lbl2.text("");
 }
 
 function eventOnBlurHDP(e, par) {
  if (par.ver == $.fn.jquery) {
   $(this).off("focus").datepicker("hide");
  }
 }
 
 function test(secs) {
  this.ver = $.fn.jquery;
  
  this.secs = (typeof secs)=='number'?secs:2;
  this.msgs = [
    'This will lose focus to box below '+this.secs+' seconds after it gains focus.',
    'Losing focus in '+this.secs+' seconds!',
    'Focus now on bottom box.'
   ];
  
  this.inpDP = $('[name=datePicker]');
  this.inpNP = $('[name=nextPicker]');
  this.lbl1 = $('#dPMsg').text(this.msgs[0]);
  this.lbl2 = $('#dPMsg2');
  var par = this;
  
  this.inpDP.datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" })
   .on('focus', function(e) { eventOnFocusDP.apply(this, [e, par]) });
  this.inpNP.on('focus', function(e) { eventOnFocusNP.apply(this, [e, par]) });
  this.inpNP.on('blur', function(e) { eventOnBlurNP.apply(this, [e, par]) });
  $(document).on('blur', '.hasDatepicker', function(e) { eventOnBlurHDP.apply(this, [e, par]) });
  return this;
 }
 
 function init() {
  window.Test = test;
  setTimeout(function() {
          $(document).on('change', '.switcher, .switcher-ui', function(e) { if (window.Test) new Test(); });
          $(jQueryUISwitcher).trigger('change');
        }, 1e3);
 }
 
 if (document.readyState == "complete") init();
 else jQuery(window).on('load', init);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/JDMcKinstry/cfc32292cbbfa548fb9584db05b2b2fc/raw/4f16f7ee441dfb98aa166a2e84193b14574a46d1/jquery.switcher.js"></script>
<form action="javascript: void 0">
  <input type="text" name="datePicker" id="dP" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
  <label for="dP" id="dPMsg"></label>
  <hr />
  <input type="text" name="nextPicker" placeholder="tab to here" />
  <label for="dP" id="dPMsg2"></label>
</form>
<hr />
<hr />
<hr />
```

Comment: This causes the datepicker to hide if you click the next or previous month buttons.

Comment: @user1 .. on the newer versions of jqueryUI

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modified solution that worked for me:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").each(function (index, element) {
    var context = $(this);
    context.on("blur", function (e) {
        // The setTimeout is the key here.
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!context.is(':focus')) {
                $(context).datepicker("hide");
            }
        }, 250);        
    });        
});
```

Comment: LOL, not exactly elegant.. but it WORKS.  And nothing else did...  Thanks!

Comment: "write less, do more"

Comment: Doesn't work. When selecting year or month via dropdown, the date picker hides itself.

Answer (score 1):

My version of js:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () {   

    $("#dtp1").on("dp.change", function (e) {    
        $('#dtp1').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });

});
```

I hope it's help you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$("#datepickerTo").datepicker({
    onSelect: function () {
        $(this).off( "focus" );
    }        
});
```