# jQuery UI datepicker doesn't hide when click outside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I found a problem with jQuery UI Datepicker on my site.

When I click on the input, it does show a `datepicker` properly. 
Nevertheless, when I don't select any date and I just click outside the element, it doesn't hide the datepicker as I'd expect.

When I press the Esc, it disappears, when I select a day it disappears but when I click outside it stays there.

Is there anyone who is able to find the problem?

Link: http://pec.solarismedia.net/index.html#content

Comment: A link to your page would be verrry helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134613/jquery-close-datepicker-when-input-lose-focus

Comment: Perhaps one of the _other_ scripts is trapping document clicks and discarding them. Disable the other scripts (e.g. the slider) and see if that helps.

Comment: Sure, there is problem with select box plugin (http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your datepickers have the class `hasDatepicker`, so try this:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").blur(function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```

I'm 99% positive that will work!

And FYI, if you want it to be dynamic (apply to inputs created after), you can use .on

```
$(".hasDatepicker").on("blur", function(e) { $(this).datepicker("hide"); });
```

> **UPDATE** <sup>(PS, to use the following completely remove the above from your code)</sup>

To answer your comment, the following may not be the best solution, but through trial and error (on your site, using console) it works! And it's relatively short compared to alternate ways I thought of.

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    var ele = $(e.toElement); 
    if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length)
       $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide"); 
});
```

As One Line

```
$(document).click(function(e) { var ele = $(e.toElement); if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length) $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide"); });
```

the problem i encountered was being able to tell when the span icon was clicked, it wasnt really wanting to cooperate, thus the extra has class checks

Comment: Actually, I found out it does make a problem when I'd like to select next month in datepicker. It hides it istead of showing the following or previous month. Any suggestion?

Comment: Awesome answer, but $(e.toElement) does not work for me, $(e.target) worked.

Comment: This breaks on I.E. 11

Comment: @Decave figures. I'll fix it when i have a chance to dl 11 and see what they've screwed up now ...

Comment: Thanks in advance. I hate IE as much as the next sane person, and appreciate your effort.

Comment: A tweaked version of the last example helped me fix this on iPad. I changed the first line to be:  $(document).on('touchstart', 'body', function (e) {

Answer (score 11):

I slightly modified the code from @SaraVanaN and it looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var elem = $(e.target);
    if(!elem.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && 
        !elem.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && 
        !elem.hasClass("ui-icon") && 
        !elem.hasClass("ui-datepicker-next") && 
        !elem.hasClass("ui-datepicker-prev") && 
        !$(elem).parents(".ui-datepicker").length){
            $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('hide');
    }
});
```

i changed this line `$(document).on("click", function(e) {` but it doesn't matter how you do it with `.on("click")` or `.click()`
and this line `!$(elem).parents(".ui-datepicker").length` i took of `.parent()`
worked for me, you should recheck your webpages datepicker, because right now, for me, when you click on a date the `div` which pops up with dates closes instantly and you can't choose any of the dates...

Comment: Very well done solution, fixes the @SpYk3HH answer when you select different month, the datepicker was closing.

Answer (score 3):

Checking here for better solutions than what I had, but I think I like my solution

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();

  $(".hasDatepicker, .ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("body").bind("click touchstart", function(event) {
    $('.ui-datepicker').hide();
    $('.hasDatepicker').blur();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```

Comment: by adding this 
$("body").bind("click touchstart", function(event) {
    $('.ui-datepicker').hide();
    $('.hasDatepicker').blur();
  });
it totaly blocked my calendar.. not even open now.

Comment: The entire `$(function() ...` block is needed, especially the `stopPropagation()`

If that line is missing then essentially every click will result in hiding the datepicker (or not showing in the first place)

Comment: Make sure you have the  `stopPropagation`

Explanation: the first part is just wiring up the datepicker element, then stopPropagation prevents clicks events to the element from propagating to it's parents (since all elements have `body` as a parent). Lastly, when a click event otherwise propagates to body it hides the datepicker

Comment: Calendar is closing now click on left and right corner in ipad. But next time calendar is not open until click on another control and again click on calendar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want do not hide calendar when you click next/prev month apply following code..

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    var ele = $(e.toElement); 
    if (!ele.hasClass("hasDatepicker") && 
        !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker") && 
        !ele.hasClass("ui-icon") && 
        !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker-next") && 
        !ele.hasClass("ui-datepicker-prev") && 
        !$(ele).parent().parents(".ui-datepicker").length)
       $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide"); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modified solution that worked for me:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").each(function (index, element) {
    var context = $(this);
    context.on("blur", function (e) {
        // The setTimeout is the key here.
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!context.is(':focus')) {
                $(context).datepicker("hide");
            }
        }, 250);        
    });        
});
```

Comment: Funny how people would down vote a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter version of the above code, bit easier to read:

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    if (!$(e.target).parents('.ui-datepicker').length)
        $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('hide');
});
```

Comment: I liked the brevity of this one, but the target was undefined in my tests. If this happens to you, change !target to !$(e.target)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
var datePickerHover = false;

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function (e) 
    {
        datePickerHover = true;
    },
    mouseleave: function () 
    {
        datePickerHover = false;
    }
}, ".datepicker");

$(document).on('mouseup','html',function()
{
    if(datePickerHover == false) $('.datepicker').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution ..

below You may find this code with merged if()s

```
var datepickerHideFix = function() {

$(document).on("click", function (e) {

    var elee = $(e.target);

    if (!elee.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {

        if (elee.isChildOf('.ui-datepicker') === false) {

            if (elee.parent().hasClass('ui-datepicker-header') === false) {

                $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('hide');
            }
        }
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
});
};
```

Merged if()s

```
var datepickerHideFix = function() {

$(document).on("click", function (e) {

    var elee = $(e.target);

    if (!elee.hasClass('hasDatepicker') &&
        elee.isChildOf('.ui-datepicker') === false &&
        elee.parent().hasClass('ui-datepicker-header') === false) {

        $('.hasDatepicker').datepicker('hide');
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It looks like this is addressed and fixed in the latest development version, which you can get from here:

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

I'm using the defaults, which seem to work. There must've been a bug in the earlier version(s).

Comment: The link provided does not seem to be the jQuery datepicker plugin.

Answer (score 0):

in init method for calendar initialization in js file find the div in which your opened calendar is there.
Like i have :

```
div.className="calendar-box";
```

//i am having datepicker on "#container" element

> $(document).unbind('click').bind("click", function (e) {
>
> ```
> if($(e.target).parents(".calendar-box").length == 0 && (e.target).id != 'container')
> {
>        //code to hide calendar..
> }   });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();

  $(".hasDatepicker, .ui-datepicker, .ui-datepicker-trigger").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $("body").bind("click touchstart", function(event) {
    $('.ui-datepicker').hide();
    $('.hasDatepicker').blur();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", function (e) {
    var elem = e.target.offsetParent;
    if (elem &&
       !elem.classList.contains("ui-datepicker") &&
        !elem.classList.contains("ui-datepicker-calendar") &&
        !elem.classList.contains("ui-datepicker-header") &&
        !elem.hasAttribute("scope") &&
        !elem.classList.contains("ui-datepicker-week-end") &&
        !elem.classList.contains("input-cal-wrapper") &&
        !elem.classList.contains("picto-cal")
    ) {
        $(".hasDatepicker").datepicker("hide");
    }
});
```

Comment: please consider also explaining what you have also done in your code

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this solution. collected from another source. this work for me. I have a button which pop-up jquery datepicker. and does not close on outside click of datepicker.

```
<script>
var mouse_is_inside = false;

$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#j-calender').hover(function(){ 
      mouse_is_inside=true; 
    }, function(){ 
        mouse_is_inside=false; 
    });

    $("body").mouseup(function(){ 
        if(! mouse_is_inside) $('.ui-datepicker').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```