# Jquery Date Picker auto closing issue

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery date picker in my site you can see that in this link https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/.

Actually my site is online ticketing base.Now the issue is that when i click on date picker area ,date picker area appears but when i click on any other field area that date picker doesn't close.

You can understand my question better in this link what actually i want.

http://screencast.com/t/d6rYUo40wdd4

Now you understand what i want.

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI datepicker doesn't hide when click outside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333571/jquery-ui-datepicker-doesnt-hide-when-click-outside)

Comment: share the code, so we can easily guide you.