# Close Jquery datepiker on date select

Tags: jquery, datepicker, forceclose, onselect

I have been using the jquery datepicker and it was working fine till the time I used custom validator and required field validator on the date textbox.
I have noticed that it is not closing on date select.
I need a hint, how can I close my datepicker manually after selecting a date?

```
 function bindPicker() {
        $("input[type=text][id*=Date]").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: "-100:+0",
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "../images/Calender.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try this

```
function bindPicker() {
    $("input[type=text][id*=Date]").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../images/Calender.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        onSelect: function(date) {
          $( "input[type=text][id*=Date]" ).datepicker("hide");
        }
    });
}
```

Or you can create an onBlur [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134613/jquery-close-datepicker-when-input-lose-focus) that will hide it:

```
$("#dateInputElementIdGoesHere").blur(function() {
  $( "input[type=text][id*=Date]" ).datepicker("hide");
});
```

Comment: Well I just did this. What could be the reason for the abnormal behavior of the datepicker on this specific page?

Comment: No clue what causes that behaviour

Comment: Sort of I just added a function in Onselect and then I just blurred it.